# The number of ways the king

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let the king stand in the upper left corner on an 8x8 chessboard. How many options to get to the cell number $ (i,j), i,j \in \{1,2 \ldots 8\}$ if the king goes to each cell no more than once?

I do not know combinatorics very well, but I am very curious about the result. Sorry for not making any attempts.

p.s. it's not homework.

Comment: It’s easier to work out by for smaller boards. Try that, and then see if patterns emerge which you can generalize.

Comment: The king has to go to every square and can move diagonal, right?

Comment: yes, diagonal.....

Comment: No more than one. Not for everyone

Comment: So to clear things up, the king is allowed to move diagonal en needs to visit every cell once until it reaches the last cell (i,j)?

Comment: Not. That's right, except that every cell needs to be visited.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is generally in [NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) class of complexity and cannot be solved only through numerical analysis. Check out [Self-avoiding walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk)

P.S. If it was a homework, it would have taken 2 or 3 month to solve it!